# 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'contactName' Blocking my loop

Tags: core-data, swift

I am looking for the best way to read data from coredata in a function and loop over the results after the fact.

I have tried it a number of ways but seem to get hung up on trying to get to the specific pieces of data within each object.

Here is my setup.

```
    func readData()->NSArray{
    let entityName:String = "Properties"
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    // Specify what this will be working with
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)

    // This will return instance of the object needed. Without which this would be
    // a pain to work with. This bit saves a few steps.
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    // Get the data and put it into a variable
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    return results!
}
```

And I call it here..

```
var properties = Properties()
    var getInfo = properties.readData()
    println(getInfo)

    for eachInfo:AnyObject in getInfo{
        println(eachInfo)
    }
```

And that dumps out something like this...

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7f87fa711d60> (entity: Properties; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://F627AD12-3CEC-4117-8294-616ADEE068DC/Properties/p1> ; data: {
acreage = 0;
conditionId = 0;
contactBusinessName = nil;
contactEmail = nil;
contactName = Bob;
contactPhoneNumber = 456456456;
isFav = nil;
latitude = 0;
longitude = 0;
price = 0;
propertyCity = nil;
propertyId = nil;
propertyState = nil;
propertyStreetAddress = nil;
propertyType = 0;
propertyZip = nil;
squareFeet = 0;
year = 0;
```

})

And that is great.  But when I go to access the data within with the below code....

```
for eachInfo:AnyObject in getInfo{
        println(eachInfo.contactName)
    }
```

I get the following error.

> "'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'contactName'"

I am sure that there is something simple I am missing but I can't find it online.

Any assist or even a better way would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Answered.**

First, Add namespace to core-data objects.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNNLo.png

Second, strongly type the output of the function so that the data is typed to the custom object.  In this case it is called "Properties".

```
    func readData()->Array<Properties>{


    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    // Specify what this will be working with
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)

    // This will return instance of the object needed. Without which this would be
    // a pain to work with. This bit saves a few steps.
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    // Get the data and put it into a variable
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    return results! as Array<Properties>


}
```

Lastly, call on the function and loop over the data.

```
       var properties = Properties()
    var getInfo = properties.readData()

    for eachInfo in getInfo{

        println(eachInfo.contactName)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
func readData()->Array<Properties>{
    let entityName:String = "Properties"
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    // Specify what this will be working with
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)

    // This will return instance of the object needed. Without which this would be
    // a pain to work with. This bit saves a few steps.
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

   // Get the data and put it into a variable
   var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

   return results! as Array<Properties>
}

var getInfo:Array<Properties> = properties.readData()
println(getInfo)

for eachInfo in getInfo{
    println(info.contactName)

}
```

I do not have a Mac here but I'm pretty sure somthing like this works. This way you have strongly typed data.

Comment: Even when I do that, on the receiving end it still wants to treat it like "AnyObject".

Causes issues with this..


var properties = Properties()
        var getInfo = properties.readData()

        for eachInfo:Array<Properties> in getInfo{
            println(eachInfo.contactName)
            
        }

And this causes an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

var properties = Properties()
        var getInfo = properties.readData()

        for eachInfo in getInfo{
            println(eachInfo.contactName)
            
        }

Comment: Your method does work.  I just have to make sure that I have the namespace added when I setup my Coredata objects.  I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

When passing the result back as an NSArray, it needs to be cast, in this case, into the NSManageObject class.

So the correct call and display of a single piece of info inside of the return looks like this.

```
var properties = Properties()
    var getInfo = properties.readData()
    println(getInfo)

    for eachInfo:AnyObject in getInfo{

        // Cast AnyObject type into the equavalent NSManagedObject.  
        let info = eachInfo as Properties
        println(info.contactName)

    }
```